# Finishing running php functions before header()

Tags: php, mysql

I have on my website a form to complete (including file import input and several other standard text inputs).
I use $_POST() to retrieve the input data, and then call php functions to save the data in mysql database.

Once the form is completed and the submit button pressed (`<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`), I want all the php functions to run and then **and only then** redirect to another page (using `header()` ).

The problem is we must put `header()` before calling our php function or else php returns error. Therefore `header()` is placed before the php functions .

This is what it looks like :

```
if(isset($_POST)){
header("Location: other_page.php");

save_name($_post['name']);
//... more php functions to save data(including input file)
}
```

This isn't a problem most of the time, but sometimes it seems that the page is redirected before all of the php functions have been run correctly wich obviously is a big problem ...

I think it is caused when the functions take too long to run (ie When the input file is too big ?), and the redirect takes effect before the functions have time to finish.

If i could get some help as to get around this problem, it would be great ! =)

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is we must put header() before calling our php function or else php returns error.

No. You just need to enable PHP's [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) feature, which will most likely solve your problem.

Comment: Ah great ! I wasn't aware of that possibility . So if i put header() after the functions, does that mean all the function will be run before the redirect ?

Comment: Yes, as per docs: *The Output Control functions allow you to control when output is sent from the script. This can be useful in several different situations,* ***especially if you need to send headers to the browser after your script has begun outputting data.***

Comment: Using the simple example above; how would you implement this ? 
(Sorry, I am new to this :S)